# Push comma separated string to new property in object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I am trying to loop through an object of strings, occasionally it will return some that is a comma separated list. I want to split those into their own properties.

Currently I am getting this

```
emailList = {
  0: "email-1@site.com",
  1: "email-2@site.com,email-3@site.com,email-4@site.com,email-5@site.com",
  2: "email-6@site.com",
  3: "email-7@site.com,email-8@site.com"
}
```

But need it like this

```
emailList = {
  0: "email-1@site.com",
  1: "email-2@site.com",
  2: "email-3@site.com",
  3: "email-4@site.com",
  4: "email-5@site.com",
  5: "email-6@site.com",
  6: "email-7@site.com",
  7: "email-8@site.com",
}
```

My thought was to try something like

```
var listSplt = '';
for(key in emailList){
    listSplt += emailList[key].split(',');
}
```

But that is giving me `undefinedemail-1@site.comemail-2@site.com,email-3@site.com,email-4@site.com,email-5@site.comemail-6@site.comemail-7@site.com,email-8@site.com` where I get an undefined in the beginning and no comma after 1.

I also feel this solution to turn it back into an Object would be a bit taxing or overly complicated. The other problem I need to watch out for is I cannot use ES6 as the system I am running it on is not up to date.

Comment: Why aren't using an array for `emailList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
var emailList = {
  0: "email-1@site.com",
  1: "email-2@site.com,email-3@site.com,email-4@site.com,email-5@site.com",
  2: "email-6@site.com",
  3: "email-7@site.com,email-8@site.com"
}

var listSplt = {};
var i = 0;

for (key in emailList) {
  emailList[key].split(',').map(function(item) {
    listSplt[i] = item;
    i++;
  });
};

console.log(listSplt);
```

By adding a [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and using an index value you can create a new object with the values assigned to the intended keys.

EDIT: without using `map()`:

```js
    var emailList = {
      0: "email-1@site.com",
      1: "email-2@site.com,email-3@site.com,email-4@site.com,email-5@site.com",
      2: "email-6@site.com",
      3: "email-7@site.com,email-8@site.com"
    }

    var values = [];
    var listSplt = {};
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;

    for (key in emailList) {
      values = emailList[key].split(',');

      for(j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
        listSplt[i] = values[j];
        i++;
      };
    };

    console.log(listSplt);
```

Comment: @CodySmith If you have "map" then the JS is not THAT ancient

Comment: @mplungjan I can use Map, but I can't use const, let, or =>. I believe its on 1.7

Comment: @CodySmith you're welcome! I'm glad it worked for you :) `map()` is supported by IE9+, so it's not too bad; plus if compatibility with older browsers than that is critical, `map()` can easily be replaced with a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

```
function splitByComma(obj) {
   let result = {}
   let index = 0
   for(let key in obj) {
         const item = obj[key]
         const splitItem = item.split(“,”)
         splitItem.forEach((it)=> {
               if(it) {
                   result[index] = it
                   index++
               }
          })
    }
    return result
}
```

Where `obj` is your input object.

Non ES6:

```
function splitByComma(obj) {
       var result = {}
       var index = 0
       for(let key in obj) {
             var item = obj[key]
             var splitItem = item.split(“,”)
             for(var i = 0; i < splitItem.length; i++) {
                   const it = splitItem[i]
                   if(it) {
                       result[index] = it
                       index++
                   }
              })
        }
        return result
}
```

Comment: `result[index] = it` this can overwrite existing entries

Comment: but index is unique so it shouldn’t be an issue

Comment: That was before your edit, but now it's fine

Comment: Oh I thought you commented after the edit. Sorry my bad.

Comment: This looks great. Would you be able to help me getting it working in non ES6 JS?

Comment: @CodySmith there is no ES6 here - you can change let to var if that is too new for you

Comment: Done, edited to add non es6, I’m not too familiar with all es6 additions is if something is still es6 please do tell me I’ll change it

Answer (score 2):

For non ES6 environment, we can  use with `Array#reduce` + `Array#concat` (ES5) to concat the split emails into a single array.

The transformation from array to object can be done using `Object.assign`:

```js
var emailList = {
  0: "email-1@site.com",
  1: "email-2@site.com,email-3@site.com,email-4@site.com,email-5@site.com",
  2: "email-6@site.com",
  3: "email-7@site.com,email-8@site.com"
}

function splitEmail(obj) {
  return Object.assign({}, Object.values(obj).reduce(function(r, v) {
    return r.concat(v.split(","));
  }, []));
}
console.log(splitEmail(emailList))
```

In ES6 we can use `Object#values` go over each email, split it using `String#split` then flatten the list and map it using `Array#flatMap` and then transform it into an object:

```js
const emailList = {
  0: "email-1@site.com",
  1: "email-2@site.com,email-3@site.com,email-4@site.com,email-5@site.com",
  2: "email-6@site.com",
  3: "email-7@site.com,email-8@site.com"
}

const splitEmail = (obj) => {
  return {...Object.values(obj).flatMap(v => v.split(","))}
}
console.log(splitEmail(emailList))
```

Comment: "I cannot use ES6" was a main message

Comment: @mplungjan sorry my bad, I completely missed that, I updated as per OP's requirement